# real life application of imaginary numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having a hard time understanding what is an imaginary number, and the purpose for studying them.

I can't stop my mind from thinking "if it doesn't exist and is not 'real' why is it being studied"?

Can someone please give an example of a applicaiton of imaginary numbers and how it solved an important problem in science?

Comment: You might want to ask yourself exactly how "real" the number we popularly call $\sqrt 2$ except for the name we give it? :)

Comment: Imaginary numbers _do_ exist; they are not _real_ in the sense that they are not real numbers.